# How do I authenticate Amazon AWS Cognito calls in Jmeter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, amazon-cognito

The client seems to generate tokens in a way I cannot replicate in Jmeter. The app is not using SSO, or Google authentication. Just username/password

The Authentication flow would be similar in Postman, except Postman has an option for AWS user pools and Jmeter does not (just mentioning this in case anyone has done it manually in Postman).

I've tried everything I know of, I'm on my last straw and I can't believe apparently nobody load tests Cognito apps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [Amazon Cognito User Pools Auth API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html) - it's normal [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) so you need to start with [AUTHORIZATION endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) and once you get the key proceed to [TOKEN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) endpoint.

Alternatively you can use [AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/index.html#lang/en_us) from the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more information on bypassing OAuth login challenge in JMeter tests